# Non Readable Pom File - Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, configuration, pom.xml

I have been building a project with no issues, but suddenly encountered this error. I have attempted to remake the workspace and now get the same error every single time. I am trying to simply build and run a project using Maven, in eclipse che.

```
 Build command --> mvn clean install -f ${current.project.path}
```

Works fine.

```
 Run command --> mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="crawler.WebInterface" -Dexec.args="${current.project.path}/database ${current.project.path}/www" -f ${current.project.path}
```

And the error i now get when running the project.

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-readable POM /projects/555-hw2
: /projects/555-hw2
 (No such file or directory) @ 
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project  (/projects/555-hw2
[ERROR]   ) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-readable POM /projects/555-hw2
[ERROR]     : /projects/555-hw2
[ERROR]     (No such file or directory)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

Meanwhile, if we look at my directory

[image]
[image]

The pom file is clearly there! How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You missing reference to pom file while using -f option with mvn

Try this

`Run command --> mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="crawler.WebInterface" -Dexec.args="${current.project.path}/database ${current.project.path}/www" -f ${current.project.path} youPomFile.xml`

Answer (score 0):

just an idea ... did you check that the user you are exececuting the maven command from and the maven program itself have read/write acces to your pom file?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `mvn clean eclipse:clean`? If yes, could you post your pom.xml here?

Comment: Never use `eclipse` goals. They are deprecated.